# yield return weird behavior

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield, yield-return

I have the following code:

```
virtual public IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedIds(){
   if (_kids == null)
        yield return null;
   foreach (var current in _kids.Nodes)
        yield return current;
}
```

This piece of code is crashing at `_kids.Nodes` with a `NullPointerException` if `_kids == null`

I would expect this method to return at the precondition level if `_kids == null` but it doesn't!

**QUESTION**

Why is the precondition at the beginning of the method have no effect?

Comment: `yield return` does not stops enumeration - you should use `yeild break` as King Kong suggested

Comment: Would you consider returning an empty sequence if `_kids == null`?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Yes, that should be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
if (_kids == null)
        yield return null;
```

to

```
if (_kids == null)
        yield break;
```

this will return an empty sequence and user won't have to check the return value.

or you can rewrite is as

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedIds(){
   if (_kids == null)
        return null;

   return GetSelectedIds2();
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedIds2()
{
    foreach (var current in _kids.Nodes)
        yield return current;
}
```

Comment: Nope - OP wants `null` to be returned from enumerator if `_kids` is `null`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky OP didn't say that, and I think that it's best to return an empty sequence.

Comment: +1! thanks for the quick answer, probably the best answer as i need to  return an empty enumerable instead :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I bet he doesn't.  And he shouldn't want to even if he thinks he does...

Comment: @WillDean agree, I tend not to return nulls from methods. But I didn't see why OP did that (he could use simple `if..else` without yielding anything)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
virtual public IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedIds(){
   if (_kids == null){
      yield return null;
      yield break;
   }
   foreach (var current in _kids.Nodes)
      yield return current;
}
```

Comment: +1! thanks for the quick answer. However, I fell like the `yield return null` is redandent.

Comment: @GETah yes, it depends on the OP. I think just letting it `yield break;` is better.

Comment: Indeed. By the way, I am the OP :D

Comment: @GETah ah, I did not even notice about that :), yes if so you can remove it if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your `yield return null` is almost certainly not what you want - it doesn't stop the iteration running (as you've found), and you probably didn't want to return a null string into a collection anyway.

Just replace it with yield break.   That way you'll get an empty collection.

That or wrap the `foreach` in `if(_kids != null)`, which might be even clearer.

As to why the precondition doesn't stop the execution - that's the way that `yield return` works - imagine a method like this:

```
IEnumerable<String> GetStrings()
{
   yield return "MyFirstString";
   yield return "MySecondString";
   yield return "MyThirdString";
}
```

This will return a collection of three strings- i.e. it doesn't stop after the first `yield return`.

Comment: Or simpler, just insert `else` before the `foreach`.

Comment: If you use `yield break`, your `if(_kids != null)` would also be redundant. That point was all I commented on (before you expanded your answer).